# How to mock a ContainerRequestContext?

Tags: junit4, java-ee-8

How could you mock the ContainterRequestContext, to receive the HttpMethod(POST, GET, PATCH) from the resource class, in addition to the User Session?

**I declare in this way**:

Resource.java

```
 @POST
 @Produces("application/json")
 @RightsFilter
 public Response create(JsonObject jsonObject,
                    @Context UriInfo uriInfo,
                    @Context final SecurityContext context) {

 (code)

 return Response.status(Status.OK)
                              .entity(entity)
                              .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
 }
```

RightsFilterTest.java

```
private ContainerRequestContext requestContext;
private SecurityContext securityContext;

@Before
public void setup(){
  requestContext = mock(ContainerRequestContext.class);
  securityContext = mock(SecurityContext.class);
}


@Test
public void abort() throws Exception{

when(requestContext.getMethod()).thenReturn(Resource.class.getMethod("POST")
.toString());

}
```

**and I get as error**:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
Mockito cannot mock this class: interface 
javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext.

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the 
mailing list.
```

**I've seen**:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27279370/how-to-mock-a-securitycontext
```

**Tools**: Junit4.12, mockito-core-2.13.0

Does anyone have any why you can't mock a ContainterRequestContext?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

since ContainerRequestContext is mock, you need to mock its methods

```
@Inject
private MyFilter myFilter;    
@Mock
private ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext;
@Mock
private UriInfo uriInfo;

@Test
public void shouldFilter() {

given(containerRequestContext.getUriInfo()).willReturn(uriInfo);
given(uriInfo.getPath()).willReturn("/v1/my/url");

myFilter.filter(containerRequestContext);
}
```